# Local Server SChannel Error 36888

Tags: ssl, https, windows-server-2008-r2, iis-8

Running Windows Server 2012, I've been getting these errors ever since we converted to HTTPS a long time ago.

As I understand it, the errors are causes by devices connecting with old ciphers, that are not accepted by our server.

Until recently, the cipher stack was set to the server default but after an SSL Labs audit, we decided to remove some of the more outdated ciphers, which allowed us to attain a grade 'B' status.

Mainly RC4.

SSL Labs recommends taking out even more ciphers in order to attain a secure grade 'A' status.

While no doubt there are more casualties, the bottom line is that there has always been a great number of schannel errors - even before tweaking the cipher stack.

I have read many posts here about how to resolve such errors but it seems there are only two solutions: add more (potentially unsafe) ciphers back into the stack; or accept that safety comes first.

First question: is my understanding in the above statement correct?

Second question: what happens on the client web browser when an error occurs?

And finally, is there a 'recommended' cipher stack for IIS 8/Windows Server 2012? It seems that there are many more ciphers mentioned in posts than are in the actual stack.

Comment: "what happens on the client web browser when an error occurs?" There are tons of browsers, so either you test them out, or check their documentation. IIS Crypto does offer many useful information which you should review https://www.nartac.com/Products/IISCrypto

Comment: Thanks for the product link - will come in very useful since modifying ciphers is a bit clunky on Windows Server 2012.